# Random Walks Question

Tags: mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I am trying to solve this question by using the reflection principles.

Let a>c>0 and b>0.

A is the set of all paths of a random walk which end at c in their final n’th step.

B is the set of paths from A which first hit a and then -b.

C is the set of paths from A which first hit a and then avoid completely -b.

D is the set of paths from A which avoid –b completely before hitting a for the first time.

Write out properly in mathematical notation the sets A, B, C and
Find their respective probabilities in terms of a, b, c and n..

Comment: please label as self-study and edit your question to specify your working so far and what precisely you are stuck on.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).